# Dispatch touch event to child in custom viewgroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-emulator

Is there any way to dispatch touch event only to specific child in custom view group with stacked children.

Comment: Managing touch events in a viewgroup should help. Try this - http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

Answer (score -1):

For as long as you have reference on both, the child you want to receive the event and the parent, you can implement the parent to pass the touch to the child you wish to receive it.

can you post the code of the View?

So you can make something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(Event e){
  childToGetTheEvent.onTouchEvent(e);
}
```

Or is there any reason you cant do something like this?

Comment: Yes I have a reference to all the children

Comment: Tried something like this. but my button inside that child is taking touch outside button area

Comment: WHether we have to map parent touch position to child's x,y

Comment: Yeah post your code. Im just guessing at the moment because i dont know what you are doing in your code.