# Expanding the touch area of a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, touch, android-view

My App uses the following `ViewPager`:

[image: Screenshot]

The `ViewPager` has the same width as the display.

I added margins to the ViewPager in xml so that I can see the left(blue) and right(gray) page.
As a result everything works fine but I can only touch onto the green area to move the pages.

I want to expand the touch area to the whole screen so that I am able to touch anywhere to move the `ViewPager`.

I tried to add a `TouchDelegate`:

```
binding.pagerContainer.post {
        val rect = Rect()  
        binding.touchArea.getHitRect(rect)
        binding.pagerContainer.touchDelegate = TouchDelegate(rect, binding.viewPager)
    }
```

And in the xml:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pager_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:clipChildren="false"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/touchArea"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0">
        </View>
    </FrameLayout>
```

The `Rect` has the correct size.
I am posting a `Runnable` to be sure that the views are laid out.
I read the documentation of the `TouchDelegate`.

I have no idea why it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK.  I think I have it this time.  After some research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12168506/7292819) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18845698/7292819), I've come up with this answer.  Instead of trying to expand the area of ViewPager with TouchDelegate, I've re-routed touch events from the FrameLayout to the ViewPager.  1st, make your own FrameLayout

```
public class MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    // make sure to include all the necessary constructors here
    // with calls to super

    // only need to override 1 method
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        ViewPager pager = null;
        int count = getChildCount();
        for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            if(getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewPager) {
                pager = (ViewPager)getChildAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(pager != null) {
            return pager.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

If you know that the ViewPager will always be in the same place in the FrameLayout, the `onTouchEvent()` can be simplified to

```
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)getChildAt(0); 
    return pager.onTouchEvent(event);
```

Then you use your custom FrameLayout in the layout file

```
 <your.package.name.MyFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/pager_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    etc. etc.
```

I've tested it and this does it for me.  Hope it works for you.

Comment: GENIUS! Love you :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines in yourlayout.xml:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Try this block:

```
YOURActivityLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

            return true;//always return true 
        }
    });
```

Hope this will work

Comment: xml for the touchareaview?

Comment: Verify that in your layout @Appyx

Comment: I added your xml in my FrameLayout. I added onTouchListener to my FrameLayout. No change.

Comment: By the way, I send a code block for onTouchListener , are you aware of ActivityLayout.setOnTouchListener must be YourActivityLayout.setOnTouchListener ? @Appyx

Comment: Remove this line and try again please.android:clickable="true" @Appyx

Answer (score 0):

My viewpager had a view behind it acting as a background. I noticed that touch events sent to the inactive items to the left and right of the active item in the viewpager were sent to the background view. That gave me the idea to intercept touches there and use the viewpager's fake drag api.

I built an extension function for ViewPager2 like this:

```
fun ViewPager2.receiveFakeDragsFrom(view: View) {
    view.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
                beginFakeDrag()
                true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                if (event.historySize > 0) {
                    fakeDragBy(
                        event.x - event.getHistoricalX(0)
                    )
                }
                true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                endFakeDrag()
                requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
                performClick()
                true
            }
            else -> {
                false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my fragment while setting up the viewpager, I just called that function with the background view as the argument:

```
myViewPager.receiveFakeDragsFrom(vpBackgroundView)
```